# parear sublistas e Introducirlas en una lista mas grande con su elemento correspondiente para etiquetar (R)

Tags: r, lista

Estoy trabajando en un código que haga muestras de diversas distribuciones de probabilidad con múltiples parámetros. Este es el código que tengo hasta ahora desarrollado

```
setting_n <- 2 

# Normal samples ----
norm_settings <- list(
  n     = as.list( rep(setting_n,setting_n)),
  mu    = as.list( rnorm(setting_n, 100,50)),
  sigma = as.list( abs(rnorm(setting_n, 5,10)) ) 
)

args_norm <- list(
  n    = norm_settings$n,
  mean = norm_settings$mu,
  sd   = norm_settings$sigma)

normal_samples<- pmap(args_norm, rnorm)
```

al llegar a normal_samples el output consiste en una lista de 5 elementos en los que el primer subelemento es un vector con la muestra para esas condiciones. Quiero agregarle un segundo elemento, sea vector o lista, a esa lista que sea las condiciones en las que la muestra fue creada, es decir, que recoja **n**, **mean** y **sd**.

es decir un output parecido a:

```
> normal_samples
[[1]]
[1] 156.7611 159.4999
[2] c(args_norm$n,args_norm$mean,args_norm$sd )

[[2]]
[1] 27.96327 82.85313
[2] c(args_norm$n,args_norm$mean,args_norm$sd )
```

El problema es que ni consigo introducirlo en la lista en la posición que quiero, ni puedo extrear los elementos ordenadamente de args_norm con map ni de otras maneras, y menos aún parearlas en la lista que me corresponde

Comment: Aitor, como la pregunta ya tiene algún tiempo pongo un mensaje para que te aparezca la notificación. Agreguéé una respuesta a tu pregunta. Ojalá te sirva y si ya le encontraste otra solución al problema también podrías publicarla aquí como respuesta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esta opción funciona, crea una lista en la que el primer elemento es una lista que contienen par de vectores con las muestras y parámetros.

Creo que la función que resuelve en gran medida el problema es `purrr::transpose()`, que pasa de un par de listas a una lista de pares. Entonces aplicándola a `args_norm` deja juntos los parámetros de cada muestra.

```
library(tidyverse)  #incluye purrr
args_norm %>% 
  transpose() %>%   #Transpongo la lista: paso de una lista de largo tres con n elementos a una lista de largo n con tres elementos 
  map(unlist) -> lista_parámetros #Simplifico con unlist para que no me quede demasiado anidada en el paso siguiente


map2(normal_samples,     #con map2 trabajo sobre dos listas al mismo tiempo: la de muestras y la de parámetros
     lista_parámetros, 
     ~list(.x, .y)) %>%  #Hago una lista nueva en la que cada elemento es un par de elementos de las listas anteriores.
  map(set_names, c("muestra", "parámetros"))  #Los nombres podrían facilitar navegar la lista más adelante, no son estrictamente necesarios.

# Estructura de la lista resultante:

List of 2
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ muestra   : num [1:2] 172 178
  ..$ parámetros: Named num [1:3] 2 179.73 4.28
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:3] "n" "mean" "sd"
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ muestra   : num [1:2] 202 207
  ..$ parámetros: Named num [1:3] 2 197 11.6
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:3] "n" "mean" "sd"
```

Comment: Gracias, es justo lo que necesitaba ^^